# Connect Android device to SAP system

Tags: android, networking

Below is the description of our app and the problems we face.Please help us to find the solution

**Application Description:**

Terminal App is utility app that can be used to manage the SAP Landscape.It is used to stop, start SAP.

**Technologies Used:**

1. Telnet Protocol
2. SSH Protocol
3. Java Programming
4. Android SDK
5. Eclipse

**Background**

In networks ,devices for example two PC’s can connect to each other using few protocols like telnet, SSH, RDP etc….These depends upon client server architecture i.e. there has to be server available to satisfy the request made from the clients.Our Terminal App also uses the Telnet /SSH protocols to connect to the SAP systems.

**Issues**

On SAP systems hosts which could be either UNIX or Windows based.Due to security reasons the ports used by Telnet /SSH protocols are generally closed in SAP environments.Asking customer to open these ports will make the system susceptible.

**Alternatives**

SAP Host Agent is a tool which is installed in SAP instances in its kernel. 
It connects to SAP Instance using a web URL and executes commands like startsapsrv and stopsapsrv.
We are trying to use SAP Host Agent in our app to start and stop SAP. 
But SAP Host Agent is built with Applet and Android browsers do not support Applets, so we are unable to use it in our App.

**Possible Solution**

What we require is tool which performs same functionality of SAP Host Agent, which can be used in Android or a way to use SAP Host Agent in Android.